# Question about Hamiltonian action

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

In Salamon&Mcduff's book p195, they claim

*The question obviously arises as to which circle actions are Hamiltonian.
An
obvious necessary condition is that a Hamiltonian action on a compact symplectic
manifold must have fixed points which correspond to the critical points of H.*

For me, it is not obvious, I wonder why ?

Another question is, below this, they claim that

*Any Hamiltonian function H on a compact manifold M has critical points.*

I also do not know why.

Comment: Could you add more context? Is $H$ a Hamiltonian function $H:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or is it a more general **moment map** for some Hamiltonian action of a Lie group on $M$?

Comment: Should it be just a function, by the Weirstrass theorem, a continuous real valued function on a compact space must attain its minimum and maximum, and thus there are at least two critical points.

Comment: @topolosaurus You are right, I made things complicated, while didn't think of the simplest conclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are so kind. @topolosaurus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@topolosaurus has addressed your second question. To answer your first: at a critical point $p$,
$$
(dH)_p = 0 \iff (i_{X_H}\omega)_p=0 \iff X_H(p) = 0,
$$
where $X_H$ denotes the Hamiltonian vector field associated with Hamiltonian $H$, and the second iff follows from non-degeneracy of the symplectic form $\omega$. Since $X_H$ generates the circle action (meaning $X_H(p) = \frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}\Phi_t(p)$, where $\Phi_t:M\to M$ is the circle action), it follows that $\Phi_t(p) = p$, i.e. $p$ is a fixed point of the action.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome :)